# How do i make my HTML page to remain after clicking submit?

Tags: javascript, html

I want after the user enter submit that the page will not change.

```
        <script src="doAction.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <form name = "ex4Param" id="ex4Param"  method="post" onsubmit="doAction();" >
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Input section</legend>
        Query Sequence:<br/>
        <td><textarea rows="5" cols="84" id="enhancers" name="charSequence"></textarea></td>
             <form/>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for an Ajax asynchronous http post.

Answer (score 1):

`onsubmit="return doAction();"`

In doAction:
`return false`